# Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install Slow

Tags: system-installation, amd-processor

My desktop is slow when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the computer is slow like the computer take five minutes to open an application. It is very sluggish. I just changed the display driver to nividia because the X.org driver kept make Ubuntu crashing. Also my computer has 2gb of ram and AMD 1.5 GHz cpu. It takes long even trying to open system menu at the top of corner.

Comment: You may try to install 12.04, it requires less resources.

Comment: Yeah, it's a resource issue, you might try installing Xubuntu as the interface is much lighter on your resources and has less system services loading on startup.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 it fast and working but all the repositories are all outdated and software center keeps saying please connect to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

load xfce-desktop and select XFCE as your desktop on the login screen. It will use less resources.

The only problem you will have after that would be removing UNITY and all the other apps and system services that were installed with it, that may be bogging down your machine.

I would just do fresh install with xubuntu and see how it goes. Backup your files first of course.

You will for sure wand to get rid of zeitgeist and any other service that will automatically index your files and other such services.